# Using one-point rule to proof properties of imperative statements

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a problem proving a logic equality in the context of the generation of verification condition for imperative non-deterministic programs. I have the following formulas that describe the change in the state of the program for certain constructs:

$R(havoc(x)) = \land_{v \in V \setminus \{x\} } v' = v$ where $V$ is the set of variables of the program.

$R(assume(F)) = F \land \land_{v \in V} v' = v$

$R(c_1;c_2) = \exists \overline{z}. R(c1)[\overline{x'}:=\overline{z}] \land R(c_2)[\overline{x}:=\overline{z}]$ where the $\overline{.}$ denotes possible vector values (a vector of variables) and in the first part of the conjunction $\overline{x'}$ refers to the output varaible states after $c_1$ and in the second part of the conjunction $\overline{x}$ refers to the input state for $c_2$.

The havoc primitive gives a non-specified value to variable x and the assume F stops any execution where F doesn't hold. The last primitive is normal sequential composition.

I should be able to proof with this primitives that $R(assume(f);c) ) = F \land R(c)$ and that $R(c;assume(F)) = R(c) \land F[\overline{x}:=\overline{x'}]$ however I'm not able to do it.

Take for instance the second case, I arrive to $\exists \overline{z}. R(c) [\overline{x'}:=\overline{z}] \land F[\overline{x} := \overline{z}] \land \overline{x'} := \overline{z}$ from here I'm supposed to use [one-point rule](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15671-f95/www/handouts/proof/node1.html) to get to the expected equality $R(c) \land F[\overline{x}:=\overline{x'}]$. I understand the second part of the conjuction but why the first part can be simplied to $R(c)$?

Comment: We have that  $∃z.R(c)[x′:=z]$ is the formula $∃z.R(c)$ with $z$ in place of $x'$. When we use the one point rule with $x':=z$ what we get is :  $∃z.R(c)[x':=x']$ (here $z$ is the $x$ of the linked rule and $x'$ is the $t$). The result of the application of the rule must have $t$ in place of $x$, i.e. $x'$ in place of $z$.

Comment: But the subst $[x':=x']$ does not change nothing and thus the result is $∃z.R(c)$. But we have replaced $z$ with $x'$ and thus in $∃z.R(c)$ there are no occurrences if $z$ any more. This means that we have a "null" quantification, and thus the formula $∃z.R(c)$ is equivalent to $R(c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is than sequential composition rule must be rewritten or understood in the following manner:

$R(c_1;c_2) = \exists \overline{z}. R(c1)[\overline{x'}:=\overline{z}] \land R(c_2)[\overline{x}:=\overline{z}]$

So here $\overline{x'}$ in the first formula should be equal to $\overline{x}$ in the second formula because the output of the first command should be equal to the input of the second command.

Therefore, the rule should be rewritten in a convenient manner.